# What the best resource to learn ANSI SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, specifications, ansi-sql

I don't mean "Basic SQL", but strongly the specs and the difference between the specs and the implementations between great databases (like SQL Server, Oracle, etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [amazon.com](http://images-eu.amazon.com/images/P/0596004818.01.jpg))</sub>

---

[SQL In a Nutshell](https://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596518851.do) by O'Reilly and Associates. It covers all 5 major SQL Dialects, the differences between them, and does that for each function/feature listed. (ANSI SQL99, Oracle, MySql, Postgres, and SQL Server).

Comment: Love that book! Really helpful if you are moving from Oracle to SQL Server or vice versa. I only wish it had Access Jet SQL as well as many people have trouble with the changes to syntax when they move away from Access.

Comment: This book has saved my rear-end more times than I care to count.  Well worth the cost.

Comment: It's a great book, but it *is* only a 'nutshell' book and leaves a lot of the standard uncovered. Any suggestions for more detail, short of buying the standard itself (yikes!)?

Comment: @bobince: Have you read this book?  It pours through every conceivable function and compares it across all 5 standards.  There's very little it leaves out.

Answer (score 1):

The number one way of learning the differences is to work in the various databases.

SQL Server, Oracle, and MySql all offer free (express) editions.  Also, if you want to step up a bit you can get the developer version of SQL Server for about $50.

Oracle:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/database/xe/index.html

SQL Server
http://www.microsoft.com/express/sql/default.aspx

MySQL
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Simple things to do:

- create a database
- create a table
- do simple insert/update/delete (CRUD) operations
- do inner / outer joins.

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlzoo.net/

[PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/) the world's more advanced opensource and more [ANSI SQL-compliant](http://www.postgresql.org/about/advantages) database

Various RDBMS ANSI SQL-conformance: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/